# Computed Column Specification in SQL Server - Time Difference in hours or minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to have a column in the table which auto-calculates the time difference between the start date and the end date as such?

```
(datediff(hour,[StartTime],[EndTime]))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
ADD yourColumn AS (datediff(hour,[StartTime],[EndTime]))
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb162/1)**

*EDIT:*
That was the syntax for alter table, off-course you can also define it during table creation

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 
(
    startDate DATETIME, 
    enddate DATETIME,
    diffCol AS (datediff(hour,startDate,enddate))
);
```

SSMS also have an option in table designer to add formula for computed columns

Comment: Might also be worth adding a case statement for NULLS, eg `CASE WHEN ISNULL([StartTime],[EndTime]) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE datediff(hour,[StartTime],[EndTime]) END`

Comment: @bendataclear No need. If one of the datetimes in DATEDIFF is null, result is also NULL - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff56e/1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both StartTime and EndTime are columns on the same row of your table, you can use a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD TimeDiffHours AS DateDiff(hour,[StartTime],[EndTime]);
```